# django.shortcuts.redirect with arguments

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect to a URL with an argument.
part of views.py

```
def membership(request):
    errors = []
    members = Member.objects.all()
    ...
        if request.POST.get('subject', '') == "member_details":
            member = members.filter(id = request.POST.get('member', ''))
            return redirect("/membership/details/", m = member)
    ...

    return render(request, "membership.html", {"errors": errors, 'members': members})
```

I need to redirect to "membership/details/" but with "member" as argument or at least members ID.

Here is a part of my url.py:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^input/book/', 'library_app.views.input_book'),
url(r'^membership/$', 'library_app.views.membership'),
url(r'^membership/details/', 'library_app.views.member_details'),
url(r'^$', 'library_app.views.main'),
```

and the "member_details" part of my views.py:

```
def member_details(request, m="doesn't work"):
    error = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        pass

    return render(request, "member_details.html", {'m': m})
```

### Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include the member in the url, then add a [named group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) to your url pattern. For example, you could include the member id with something like:

```
url(r'^membership/details/(?P<member_id>\d+)/', 'library_app.views.member_details', name='member_details'),
```

Your view would then include `member_id` as a keyword argument.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def member_details(request, member_id):
    member = get_object_or_404(id=member_id)
    # you might want to add checks to make sure 
    # that the logged in user is allowed to see this members details!
    ...
```

You can then use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) with a hardcoded url:

```
return redirect("/membership/details/%s/ % member.pk")
```

Or, it's better to include the view name and member_id as an argument.

```
return redirect("member_details", member_id=member.id)
```